# Monit : Service Name is not capitalized as configured in the monit control file

Tags: monit

If monit is configured with a check program as follows

check process DBServer matching jdbs
 start program = "run_script.sh"

I see "dbserver" as the service name under mmonit instead of "DBServer".

It does have "DBServer" as the $SERVICE value when an email alert is raised.

Any thoughts?

Monit version: 5.21.0
M/Monit version: 3.7.0-linux-x64

Answer (score 0):

per MMonit support

The service names (and servicegroup names) are normalized to lowercase intentionally to deduplicate similar names (M/Monit stores them internally in a lookup table and normalization allows to make it smaller).